# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework (VS 2022)

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

after installing restsharp package I can't run `add-migration` or `update-database` command and I am getting same error when running project.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I know there are many threads that talked about this issue but I tried all solutions and the problem is not solved.

Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise (17.3.3)

I tried these solutions :

- Modifying MSbuild path in devenv.exe.config
- Adding 'Micfrosoft.Build.Framework.dll' to global assembly cache
- Restarting visual studio
- Repair visual studio
- Removing RestSharp package
- Reinstalling nuget packages
- Removing *.csproj.user

Comment: Does this issue appear for all the projects(include the newly created projects)? If you install a standalone [Microsoft.Build.Framework NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Framework) will it work?

Comment: @Tianyu Thanks for your comment, No just for one project ... Apparently the issue solved by installing Microsoft.Build.Framework nuget package. I checked my models and found a using Microsoft.Build.Framework. That was added by `[Required]` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the nuget "Microsoft.Build" or "Microsoft.Build.Framework" from the Top-level packages if are on the Transitive packages dont have problem. I hope that helps you